# writing select from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

```
1. Table events: event_date, name, event
2. Table locations: loc_date, name, location
```

I need to get all rows from table events and locations from table locations where **loc_date last before event_date.**

**Update** I need to get one location for each row from table **events**. For example:

```
events
event_date | name | event
13:53      | test1| 0
14:20      | test2| 1
18:00      | test3| 5

locations
location_date | name | location
13:20         | a    | Moscow
13:40         | b    | New-York
14:00         | c    | London
17:24         | d    | Tokio
18:00         | e    | Berlin
```

and the result I want is:

```
event_date | name  | event | location
13:53      | test1 | 0     | New-York
14:20      | test2 | 1     | London
18:00      | test3 | 5     | Berlin
```

I've tried something like this:

```
select e.*
from events e
left join locations l on l.loc_date < e.event_date
```

But this query returns a lot of rows with same data from events and different data from locations.

Comment: I've tried smth like this:
select events.* from events as e left join locations as l on l.loc_date<event_date.
But this query returns a lot of rows with same data from events and different data from locations.

Comment: you wrote `all rows` and `last before`? m not clear with your requirement. Do you need immediate first row on the basis of  loc_date < event_date order by loc_date desc?

Comment: I'm sorry. I updated question and added a example.

Answer (score 0):

Prolly something like this:

```
select e.* from events e
inner join location l on l.loc_date < e.event_date
```

But this is not a good schema, you should have something to link both tables properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) [first_value()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions066.htm#SQLRF00642) for this:

```
select distinct e.event_date, e.name, e.event,
    first_value(l.location)
        over (partition by e.event_date, e.name, e.event
            order by l.loc_date desc) as location
from events e
left join locations l on l.loc_date < e.event_date
order by e.event_date, e.name, e.event;

EVENT NAME       EVENT LOCATION
----- ----- ---------- --------
13:53 test1          0 New-York
14:20 test2          1 London
18:00 test3          5 Tokio
```

Note that the `test3` location is Tokio, not Berlin as you had in your expected results; that's because you specified 'loc_date *last before* event_date', and Berlin's `loc_date` is the same as the `event_date`. If you do want it to match on that, you need to use `<=` instead of `<`.

The non-analytic way to do it is with a correlated subquery, which has to hit the table twice; I prefer the analytic way but this may be easier to follow:

```
select e.event_date, e.name, e.event, l.location
from events e
join locations l on l.loc_date = (
    select max(loc_date) from locations
    where loc_date < e.event_date
)
order by e.event_date, e.name, e.event;
```

Comment: This `loc_date < event_date` should be `loc_date <= event_date` else third row of result will not be part of the same.

Comment: @manurajhada - yes, I mentioned that in the answer - as it is, it's showing Tokio instead of Berlin. It's not clear which it's supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Both of these variants are working, but we have one BIG problem. Table with location is very big (about 4 TeraBytes) and these queries working very slow. May be is there some way to make it faster?

Comment: @Demand - possibly, but it depends if there is some other link between the tables, the relative volumes, and all sort of things. Worth checking the execution plan to see if it's doing anything unexpected. With the schema you've given - which as aF. mentioned doesn't look sensible - I guess the best you can hope for is a full table scan of both tables. If you can restrict the lower bound for data match you might see an improvement, if there are suitable indexes. Not enough detail of the real data/schema to have a clue really.